# Solve following system of nonlinear equations (Newton method diverges)

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, newton-raphson

I'm interested into a method that would solve a system of 4 equations in the following form:

$$
\frac{1}{y} + \frac{6}{z} = w,\\
\frac{3}{y} + \frac{10}{z} = x, \\
\frac{3}{w} + \frac{2.5}{x} = y,  \\
\frac{1}{w} + \frac{17.5}{x} = z \\
$$

Note that the solution is (2, 5, 2, 4). However, I am doing a research project that will require me to calculate the general form of this system of equations with parameters as constants in the numerators (so the current numbers are just placeholders).

I tried substitution, transformations, and a Newton-Rapshon algorithm in R (which unfortunately diverged).

Does anyone know of a way to compute a system of equations in this form? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $(2, 5, 2, 4)$ is not a solution: it doesn't satisfy the second equation.

Substituting $w$ and $x$ from the first two equations into the last two and simplifying gives you
$$ \eqalign{-{\frac {y \left( 120\,{y}^{2}-34\,yz-17\,{z}^{2} \right) }{ \left( 2\,z+12\,y \right)  \left( 3\,z+10\,y \right) }}&=0\cr
{\frac {z \left( 110\,{y}^{2}-15\,yz-6\,{z}^{2} \right) }{ \left( 2\,z
+12\,y \right)  \left( 3\,z+10\,y \right) }}&=0\cr}$$
Of course $y$ and $z$ can't be $0$, so that leaves you with
$$ \eqalign{ 120\,{y}^{2}-34\,yz-17\,{z}^{2} &= 0\cr
110\,{y}^{2}-15\,yz-6\,{z}^{2} &= 0\cr}$$
Each of these is the equation of two lines through the origin in the $yz$ plane,
and the slopes are all different, so the intersection is only $(0,0)$, which is not a solution of the original system.  Thus your system has no solutions.